# Как после удаления записи с БД Primary key смещался на один postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

столкнулся с проблемой что после удаления записи с БД и после этого добавления новой Primary key починается через одно значения, например:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Уже пробовал команды:

```
SELECT MAX( number_event ) FROM public.workshops;
ALTER TABLE number_event AUTO_INCREMENT = number;
```

```
update public.workshops
   set number_event = (@number_event := @number_event + 1)
   order by number_event;
```

Ищу способ, что бы после удаления записи `number_event` прономерировался в правильном порядке.

Comment: Нумеруй в запросе, а не в таблице.

Comment: Не самая удачная идея. При этом параллельные запросы получат одинаковые значения. Даже если исправллять значение в сиквенсе, используемое для ПК это тодже не шарантия при одновременных запросах. Я считаю лучше не вмешиваться в генерацию ПК базой и не использовать этот номер для бизнес-логики. В этом случае ничего страшного в пропущенных номерах не будет.

Comment: ключевой вопрос, зачем вам это надо?

Comment: @teran, я хочу удалять запись про евент с БД после того как он состоялся. Если последованность будет в разнобой то при выдачи значений будет не очень смотреться